# mPDF auto height not working

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

The results are correct.

[image]

I want to create PDF fixed width and auto height. Not up a new page.

code

```
$content = '';
$content .= '<!DOCTYPE html>';
$content .= '<body>';
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
   $content .= '<div>' . $i . '</div>';
}
$content .= '</body>';
$content .= '</html>';

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->page   = 0;
$mpdf->state  = 0;
unset($mpdf->pages);
$p = 'P';
$mpdf->_setPageSize(array(100, $mpdf->y), $p);
$mpdf->addPage('', '', 0, '', 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Invalid results.

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: So are you trying to create one very large page, or are you trying to shrink the font size so that 100 outputs will reach the exact end of a regularly sized page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426853/setting-paper-size-in-fpdf