# How to set custom page size in fpdf php library?

Tags: php, fpdf

I need some help with fPDF. I want to set up my custom page size (exactly: width 3 inch, and height 5 or 6 inch). 
**it will create number of pages again height parameter .**

> i set the size array(3,5). it will create 5 page. I

found fPDF() manual (http://www.fpdf.org/) but there are only ready formats like A4, B5 etc. I have to set up my own page format.

```
<?php 
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
//$fromat = array(3,5);
$pdf = new FPDF('p','in', [4.1,2.9]);
$pdf->SetTopMargin(50);
$pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->SetTitle("invoice");
$pdf->SetCreator("maqbool solutons");
$pdf->SetAuthor("my name");
$pdf->SetSubject("report");


$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', '16');
$pdf->SetTextColor(155,14,9);// rgb
$pdf->SetDrawColor(155,14,9);
$pdf->SetfillColor(15,140,95);
$pdf->Cell(60,10, 'hello word');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'powered by fpdf', 1, 0,'c',true);
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'powered by fpdf', 1, 2,'c');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'powered by fpdf', 1, 1,'c');
$pdf->Image("images/coat.jpg", 10,20,10,35);
$pdf->MultiCell(94,10,"skldjfsldfsfjsdkfsjdlfjsdflkjsdflksjflksjdflskjfslkjfdslkfdjslkfdjslkfjslkfjslkfjsflkjsflkjsflksjflksjfslkjfslkjslkf",1,"L",false);
$pdf->Output("I", "invice.pdf");
 ?>[that is my file size][1]
```

[when i add array of size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Wou.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting paper size in FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426853/setting-paper-size-in-fpdf)

Comment: sir my question is duplicate but it has not solution yet . ether here nor there.

Comment: Which version of PHP and FPDF are you using?

Comment: fpdf version is 1.8.1 and php version is  7.1

Answer (score 1):

As said in the documentation, when you call the `constructor` or `AddPage`, you can either give a String or an Array containing the width and height:

```
// AddPage([string orientation [, mixed size [, int rotation]]])
$pdf->AddPage("P", [3, 5]); // assuming you are using 'in' as unit
```

Or directly using the constructor:

```
// __construct([string orientation [, string unit [, mixed size]]])
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in',[3, 5]);
```

Comment: sir i try this but it will create number of pages of last parameter that i give it as for hight.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment, can you edit your post and paste the involved PHP code? And also, give us the result you get.

Answer (score 1):

You should should define it in your constructor like so:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in',[3,6]);
```

You can find more info in tutorial #1 and in the manual > AddPage

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the page size with the constructor.
I have not tested it but this should show you the way:

```
$format=array(3,5);
$pdf=new FPDF('P','in',$format);
$pdf->Open();
....
```

Comment: sir i try this but not working. it will create  pages against height parameter

Comment: Hi
Did you change your question in the meantime? I think it was only the question for the size in the beginning.

The problem now should be that you set a really big top margin which is outside of your page ...